# How does Nunit generate TestResult.xml

Tags: xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to create an XML or JSON log file after every test using Selenium and NUnit.
Instead of starting from the bottom, I noticed that NUnit creates after every test a report file called " TestResult.xml ".
The idea is that I want to know how does NUnit generate the test result document to use these parameters and create my own custom log file.
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write you own addins, and accessing tests events through [EventListeners](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=eventListeners&r=2.5.7)

[Example a of a custom addin](http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/NUnit-Test-Start-and-End-Time-Logging-Add-in.aspx)